# Can white chickpeas (chana) be offered as naivedyam in Puja?

Tags: scripture, dharma-shastras

Can white chickpeas (chana) be cooked and offered as naivedyam in Puja?

Thank you.

Comment: Offcourse, It is also given as prasad in South Indian temples, God accepts anything offered with Love!